# Как убрать класс по click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется функция, которая добавляет класс:

```
$('.co1').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("co1hover");
});
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на другой объект класс удалялся.
Такое написание:

```
$('.closew').click(function() {
    $('.co1').removeClass("co1hover");
});
```

не работает, хотя на вид должно. Что не так?
Или как это изобразить c помощью `on('click')`?

```js
$('.co1').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("co1hover");
});

$('.closew').click(function() {
    $('.co1').removeClass("co1hover");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding: 0;
}
:root {
  --heightrow: calc(94vh - 2vw);
}
.grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 6vh calc(var(--heightrow) - 1vw);
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-gap: 1vw;
}
.hed {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 5;
  background: red;
}
.co1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  width: 24vw;
}
.co2 {
  background: #444;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  width: 24vw;
}
.co3 {
  background: #aaa;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  width: 24vw;
}
.co4 {
  background: #ddd;
}
.co5 {
  background: #ccc;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
.co6 {
  background: #555;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 5;
}
.co7 {
  background: #999;
}
.co8 {
  background: #aaa;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 5;
}
.cont23 {
  padding: 1vw 1vw 1vw 1vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.co1hover {
  width: 47vw !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.co1cont {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 20vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}
.closew {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont23">
  <div class="grid1">
    <div class="hed"></div>
    <div class="co1">
      <div class="closew"></div>
      <div class="co1cont" style="color: #ff0;">
        Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
        Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="co2"></div>
    <div class="co3"></div>
    <div class="co4"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Нажать на первый квадрат, закрыть на белый в правом верхнем углу.

Comment: Добавьте ваш html, чтобы было понятнее, почему у вас не работает.

Comment: На самом деле, нужен не просто HTML, а [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). И вы пробовали отлаживать код? `.closew` существует на момент добавления обработчика события? Обработчик вызывается? `.co1` существует в момент вызова обработчика? Как вы определяете что класс не исчез?

Comment: @abooksabooks код должен быть в самом вопросе, плюс стоит из него выкинуть всё то, что не относится к вопросу напрямую.

Comment: код добавил, лишнеее из него выкинул.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как блок `.closew` находится внутри блока `.co1`, а [всплытие события](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling) `click` не заблокировано, то при клике на `.closew` вызываются оба обработчика: сначала класс удаляется, а потом снова добавляется. Можно заблокировать всплытие события:

```
$('.closew').click(function() {
    $('.co1').removeClass("co1hover");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: спасибо! работает. не подумал про оба обработчика.

Comment: @abooksabooks на здоровье. Да, приходится за этим следить и блокировать всплытие, а порой и стандартное поведение. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).